# ASP.NET MVC Rich Text Editor

Tags: javascript, controls, user-interface, rich-text-editor

### Goal

The goal of this wiki entry is to create a comprehensive list of available rich text editors for err... traditional websites.  By traditional we mean anything that isn't asp.net with server controls and viewstate.  Open source and commercial options are both viable for discussion.

### Why This Wiki

I have found bits and pieces of user feedback on which editors people like, but a lot of input lacks an equal comparison across the available solutions.

### Criteria

Editors should be compared on the following criteria:
(If people suggest more criteria I will be happy to add them if appropriate)

- Price
- Browsers supported
- Dependencies on other frameworks
- Support level/developer community
  presence
- Number & size of required include
  files
- Number of lines for basic
  functionality
- Editors visual appearance
- Generated content quality
  (POSH/XHTML)
- End user experience
- Known bugs or missing functionality
- Known quirks/general complaints

**Please include the following:**

- The name of the editor
- Version reviewed
- A link to the editor's homepage

---

## [Dojo Toolkit](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/)

Pending

## [FreeTextBox 3.2.2](http://freetextbox.com/)

Not valid as it is a server side control

## [RadEditor 2009 Q1](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx)

Not valid as it is a server side control.  I have heard a few people talking about getting the rad suite behave in asp.net mvc, so if someone wants to review this in more detail I will look at not discounting it.

## [TinyMCE 3.2.4.1](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/index.php)

pending

## [YUI Rich Text Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/)

pending

Comment: Yeah it should have been, coulda sworn the checkbox was checked

Answer (score 7):

FCKEditor

http://www.fckeditor.net/

By and far my favorite because it is 'traditional', degrades gracefully in browsers that can't handle complex javascript, and produces standards compliant code.

Comment: I've been using FCKEditor for about 7 years, and it's a wonderful little app.